# A quick way to remove fields from layouts

Tags: custom-field, standard-objects

While creating a lot a new fields to on object, I've inadvertently added them to all layouts. Is there any quick way to de-assign a field from a given layout, much like during field creation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a faster way... but a quick one is from Page Layout go in your desired layout and hold down the ctrl (also the shift works) key to select multiple fields, then just hit the Remove button from one of them

Answer (score 0):

You can try using metadata API by retrieving required layouts and remove "layoutItems" tags from metadata of desired fields and later re-deploy layouts using VSCode, Workbench, ANT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Layout xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <layoutSections>
        <layoutColumns>
            <layoutItems> ---> "Remove start"
                <behavior>Readonly</behavior>
                <field>RemoveField1__c</field>
            </layoutItems> ---> "Remove end"
            </layoutColumns>
    </layoutSections>
   </Layout>
```

Also, you might want to review [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdiLUUAZ/remove-fields-from-multiple-page-layouts) and vote for this feature.

Thanks